# Parse information of a PHP file using PHP?

Tags: php

Are there any way for me to use PHP to parse information of a PHP file, something likes : what functions/classes it has, which functions are built-in/user-defined or how many variables are there....?

Comment: More useful than just the raw token stream is a parser class like http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Parser (or even CodeSniffer) which deciphers defined functions/variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) to parse PHP source.

```
$source = file_get_contents('my-file.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($source);
```

Comment: There was also some discussion about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068007/parsing-and-printing-php-code/