# Generate AST of a PHP source file

Tags: php, parsing, lexer

I want to parse a PHP source file, into an AST (preferably as a nested array of instructions).

I basically want to convert things like

```
f($a, $b + 1)
```

into something like

```
array( 'function_call',
    array(
        array( 'var', '$a' ),
        array( 'expression',
            array(
                array( 'binary_operation',
                    '+',
                    array ('var', '$b'),
                    array( 'int', '1' )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Are there any inbuilt PHP library or third party libraries (preferably in PHP) that would let me do this?

Comment: I'm really curious. Why?

Comment: *(tip)* [Sebastian Bergmann's slides on Analyzing PHP Code](http://www.slideshare.net/sebastian_bergmann/analysing-php-code)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have implemented a [PHP Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) after I figured out that there [was no existing parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586358/any-decent-php-parser-written-in-php). It parses the PHP code into a node tree.

Comment: I just tried out your parser, and I think it may be good enough for my use. I have one problem though - there's no license file in your project, and there's no mention of anything related to that, so I'm not sure if I could use this in my project.

Comment: @Dogbert: Yes, I haven't added one yet ;) It is MIT/BSD. So you should be able to use it in pretty much any project.

Comment: @NikiC: If it doesn't contain the license, it isn't anything.  Nobody will pay any attention what you claim it is, here.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thank you for this most insightful of comments. Now look at the dates on the above comments and at the LICENSE file in the linked repository.

Comment: @NikiC:  Good that you have it. Even better that have clarified here after this long time, that it is in place.  You're welcome.

Comment: Hi, @NikiC, thank you for writing this nice parser. However, I don't know how to use it, should I compile it along with PHP7? Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

**HipHop**

You can use [Facebook's HHVM](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm) to dump the AST.

```
apt-get install hhvm

# parse specified file and dump the AST
hhvm --parse arg
```

This worked for HipHop (the old PHP to C++ compiler) - back in the days of 2013!

---

**HHVM**

Update 2015

`--parse` is not supported.

You will get an error: `HHVM The 'parse' command line option is not supported.`

See https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/c494c3a145008f65d349611eb2d09d0c33f1ab23/hphp/runtime/base/program_functions.cpp#L1111

**Feature Request** to support the CLI option again: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4615

---

**PHP 7**

PHP 7 will have an AST, see the related [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/abstract_syntax_tree).

There are two extensions, which provide access and expose the AST generated by PHP 7:

- https://github.com/nikic/php-ast
- https://github.com/sgolemon/astkit

Comment: This outputs `Error in command line: unrecognised option '--parse'` for me. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, installed the `hhvm` package from the repo at http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu as explained [here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-packages-on-Ubuntu-14.04), `hhvm --version` outputs HipHop VM 3.6.1. When I call `hhvm --help` there does indeed not seem to be a `--parse` option.

Comment: Yo! This dates back to HipHop in 2013. Updated my answer to reflect the current situation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can look at the answers from [Parsing and Printing PHP Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068007/parsing-and-printing-php-code) and [Generating PHP code (from Parser Tokens)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068285/generating-php-code-from-parser-tokens): basically PEAR's PHP_Beautifier package at http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier can be extended to do what you want, but it sounds like it requires some heavy lifting.

And if you're not constrained to PHP then http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/ast/PHP_AST.html walks you through using the Eclipse PHP module's AST parser.

Comment: Some of the links in the answers to [Is there a static code analyzer like Lint for PHP files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/378959) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Pfff](https://github.com/facebook/pfff) is an OCaml library for parsing and manipulating PHP code. See [the manual of Pfff](https://github.com/facebook/pfff/wiki/Parsing_php.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such feature built-in. But you can use the [Tokenizer](http://php.net/tokenizer) to create it.